# Error using AdMob and Google Play Game Services at the same time

Tags: android, libgdx, admob, google-play-services

I am using libgdx and Android studios. I have successfully implemented google play game services (leaderboards etc). Now I want to implement admob, but I get errors.

This is part of my build.gradle:

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(":BaseGameUtils")
}
```

}

If I press build->clean projects, everything seems fine, but when I want to run the app on my android phone, I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':android:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqv.class
```

It is the `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.0'` part that messes things up. If i remove that line, everything works as before, but I cant use AdMob.

Anyone knows what the problem might be?

When I used Eclipse, I included the google-play-service library as a project, and did not need to add anything to the build.gradle... why is it different in AndroidStudios?

Comment: what is inside `libs` ?

Comment: `tween-engine-api.jar` and `tween-engine-api-sources.jar`. And in my android/libs there are only libgdx related stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to artifact mismatch/version conflict.

Remove

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.2.0'
```

from your android dependencies tag of root `build.gradle` file, `BaseGameUtils` already have that that dependency. Check supporting version in `build.gradle` of `BaseGameUtils` module.

Also It's better to use artifact from repo insted of from `libs` folder.

You can also inject tween engine

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

compile 'com.github.arcnor:universal-tween-engine:6.3.4'
compile 'com.github.arcnor:universal-tween-engine:6.3.4:sources'
```